# "Opposite procedure" of solving a linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find a linear, homogeneous differential equation of degree 4 for which $y=x\cos{x}e^{3x}$ is a solution?

Comment: @KirylPesotski The equation you give is not homogeneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of the quartic polynomial function
\begin{equation*}
f(t) = (t^{2} - 6t + 10)^{2}
\end{equation*}
are $3 \pm i$. Any differential equation having $f(t)$ as its auxiliary function has any scalar multiple of $xe^{3x}\cos{x}$ as its solution. So,
$-9xe^{3x}\cos{x}$ is a solution to
\begin{equation*}
y^{(4)} - 12 y^{\prime\prime\prime} + 56y^{\prime\prime} - 120y^{\prime} + 100y = 0 . \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Naively, we can differentiate $y = x e^{3 x} \cos x$ four times and find some linear combination $\sum_{i = 0}^4 a_i(x) y^{(i)}(x)$ of $y, y', \ldots, y^{(4)}$ that vanishes.

---

**Hint** Alternatively, we can rewrite the function as
$$y = \tfrac{1}{2} x e^{(3 + i) x} + \tfrac{1}{2} xe^{(3 - i) x}$$ and look for such a homogeneous differential equation for which each term separately is a solution: Since the function is homogeneous, sums of solutions are solutions.

On the other hand, recall that the function $x \mapsto x e^{a x}$ is a solution of a linear, homogeneous, *constant-coefficient* differential equation whose characteristic polynomial contains the factor $(r - a)^2$.

> **Additional hint** So, we're looking for such an equation whose characteristic polynomial is divisible by both $[r - (3 \pm i)]^2$ and hence by $[r - (3 - i)]^2 [r - (3 + i) x]^2 = (r^2 - 6 r + 10)^2$.

Comment: Yes, the directions did say to find a linear, homogeneous differential equation with "constant coefficients." It is your last comment that is pertinent.